# How to display each string items in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

Here are some string items:

```
string[] r = {"item1","item2", "item3"}
```

I want to loop through GridView and add each string items to the GridView rows

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text += r[i];

    }
```

The GridView doesnt display any data... What method should use to solve this problem?

Comment: `GridView` isn't MVC. Are you actually using Web Forms? Or are you trying to use a Web Forms control in MVC?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET webforms

Comment: OK, then you should remove the mvc tags. You should read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8). It will be better than what can be written in an answer unless you have a specific question to a specific problem.

Comment: I made my research still need help I am confused if I get an example I will understand faster than I read long documents

Comment: I meant that I want to see the HTML markup of how you defined the grid.

Comment: very simple:  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249906/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-user20465780).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. Forget the loop, data-enabled controls like this are better suited to data binding than dealing with the rows directly.

```
gridview1.DataSource = r;
gridview1.Databind();
```

Comment: it doesn`t work puts long columns of chars instead putting each string item into each row

Comment: @user20465780 can you post the markup for your grid?

Comment: now I have posted

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="300px">

</asp:GridView>
```

then code behind is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }


    void LoadData()
    {

        string[] r = { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
        GridView1.DataSource = r;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

And we now get this:

[image]

However, as a general rule, you have to feed the gv a "structured" list of data.

So, that means "columns" or at least each row needs to have a "define" of the data.

We can change the above code to this:

```
    struct MyName
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CodeName { get; set; }
        public MyName(string firstName, string lastName, string sCode)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            CodeName = sCode;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }


    void LoadData()
    {

        List<MyName> MyNames = new List<MyName>();

        MyNames.Add(new MyName("Clark", "Kent", "Superman"));
        MyNames.Add(new MyName("Peter", "Parker", "Spiderman"));
        MyNames.Add(new MyName("Bruce", "Wayne", "Batman"));
        MyNames.Add(new MyName("Tony", "Stark", "Ironman"));

        GridView1.DataSource = MyNames;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

So, in most cases, you can't JUST send a list of strings, but a list with a "structure" that then becomes the column(s) for the grid view.